# Integrate a differential equation where y is a function of t

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Integrate

dy(t)/dt=

-y(t)+B(t)+C+D

where C and D are variables and B is also a function of t.

If a constant is to be added to the integral, does it become a function of t too?
The exact function and its solution is actually in the picture attached, but I do not understand how the constant K became K(t) and why the solution can be rewritten as in the last line. Thank you for your help. [image]

Comment: Do A, C, D depend on t? Or on Y? If not, then they are "constants" or "constant parameters". The variables of this system are t and y. -- What do you know about the homogeneous solution?

Comment: A,C and D do not depend on t or Y. they are just variables.

Comment: No, they are then "constants" or "parameters". Now about that homogeneous solution...

Answer (score 0):

$$y + \frac{{dy}}{{dt}} = B\left( t \right) + C + D$$

Forward with homgenous system:

$$\frac{{dy}}{{dt}} =  - y \Rightarrow \frac{{dy}}{y} =  - dt$$
$$\ln (y) =  - t + \ln (c) \Rightarrow y = c \cdot {e^{ - t}}$$

Now inhomogenous system, variation of the constant:

$$y = c(t) \cdot {e^{ - t}}$$
$$\frac{{dy}}{{dt}} = c'(t) \cdot {e^{ - t}} - y$$
$$y + \frac{{dy}}{{dt}} = c'(t) \cdot {e^{ - t}}$$
$$c'(t) \cdot {e^{ - t}} = B\left( t \right) + C + D$$
$$c'(t) = B\left( t \right) \cdot {e^t} + (C + D) \cdot {e^t}$$

Here we've got the "constant"
$$c(t) = \int\limits_a^t {B\left( u \right) \cdot {e^u}du}  + (C + D) \cdot {e^t}$$

$$y = \int\limits_a^t {B\left( u \right) \cdot {e^u}du}  \cdot {e^{ - t}} + C + D$$